# Make a google Script Run from a HTML front

Tags: html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script that will run an HTTP request to our server and bring the most recent orders.

We want to be able to run the script on request but also be able to Install it as an addon to different sheets for our different stores

The front End of the app is generated by this html

```
<link href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons.css"
     rel="stylesheet">


<div class="sidebar">

    
    <div class="block form-group">
            
        <button class="blue" id="load_orders">Import Order Data</button>
    </div>

    
    <div id='orders'></div>

</div>


<script>
  $(function onSuccess(load_orders) {
   
  
   });
  withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).importcogs();
 });
</script>
```

Then on the .gs I have a script to show the app (before we Deploy it) and the import orders script

```
function onInstall() {
  onOpen();
}


function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
  .createAddonMenu() // Add a new option in the Google Docs Add-ons Menu
  .addItem("Import Order Data", "showSidebar")
  .addToUi();  // Run the showSidebar function when someone clicks the menu
}


function showSidebar() {
  var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("Front")
    .evaluate()
    .setTitle("Import Order - Search"); // The title shows in the sidebar
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(html);
}


function importcogs() {
  Logger.log("import begin");
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var urlsheet = ss.getSheetByName("GetInfo");
  var request = urlsheet.getRange(5,2).getValue();
  Logger.log(request);

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(request);
  Logger.log("download data finish");
  Logger.log(response.getContentText());

  
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Data");
  var obj = JSON.parse(response);
  let vs = obj.data.map(o => Object.values(o));//data
  vs.unshift(Object.keys(obj.data[0]));//add header
  sheet.getRange(1,1,vs.length, vs[0].length).setValues(vs);//output to spreadsheet


}
```

I Haven't been able to link the "Import orders" button to the script for some reason .

Comment: `withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).importcogs();` is a method not a standalone function [ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication)

Comment: Hi @Cooper, could you post your comment as answer so I can upvote it? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As what Cooper has said in the above comment, it is not a standalone function:

Sample Usage:

```
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).importcogs();
```

This will in return runs the `importcogs` function and will trigger `onSuccess` function if the function successfully finished. Parameters of the `onSuccess` will be the return of the function called `importcogs` if it has any.